# Cloning a repo from my own GitHub on a new machine

Tags: repository, push, git-clone

How can I clone a repo from my own GitHub to a new machine and continue pushing to the same repo smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

On that new machine, you should make sure your user.name and user.email are correct.

```
git config --global user.name
git config --global user.email
```

Then check your git credential helper (to cache your https credentials)

```
git config --global credential.helper
```

Finally, clone, add, commit, and push back

```
git clone https://github.com/<me>/<myrepo>
cd myrepo
... add commit
git push -u origin master
```

A GUI like [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) can help.

You could also [clone with SSH](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/).